# Prove convergence of recursive sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

I have tried to solve this question in a few ways but can't reach a final solution any way I try.
**Question :**
Let $x_{n+1}=10x_n^2$ be a sequence.
Prove the sequence converges $\forall x_0 \in [-0.1,0.1]$ and diverges $\forall x_0 \notin [-0.1,0.1]$
**My try :**
Assume $L\in \mathbb{R}$ be a limit of $x_n$.
Then : $L=10L^2 \longrightarrow L(10L-1)=0$
the limit can either be $L=0$ or $L=\frac{1}{10}$
From here on I don't know how to proceed

Comment: *Hint:* With the substitution $y_n = 10 x_n$ the recursion becomes $y_{n+1} = y_n^2$, which might be easier to handle.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming languages, not in Mathematics.

Comment: First step : Notice that the sign of the start number does not matter. Hence we can assume that we start with a non-negative number. Second step : Once we have a value greater than $0.1$, the sequence cannot converge since it is strictly decreasing from this point on and cannot reach any of the two possible limits. Third step : If we are below $0.1$, but above $0$ , the sequence is strictly decreasing and bounded from below, hence converges,